# React Native Web issue (process is not defined and dispatcher is null)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

so basically the app runs fine on android/iOS but doesn't run on web

These are the following persistent errors
[image]

[image]

I apparently have figured it has something to do with **Webpack(v5?)** and **react-scripts**,
have already downgraded **Webpack** and added the **react-error-overlay** but still these errors pop-up

This is my App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Platform } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hi! Welcome</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    alignItems:'center',
    ...Platform.select({android:{backgroundColor:'orchid'}})
  },
});
```

This is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "bigapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 18+ hours trying fixes and encountering the same errors...

I have done the following

```
1)Removed the project and re-installed it using yarn

2)downgraded react to 17.0.2

3)downgraded react-native to 0.68.2

4)downgraded expo to 45.0.0

5)Added the react-error-overlay to 6.0.9 in package.json
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bigApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Still I have no idea how **webpack(v5)** is fine with outdated dependencies but nonetheless it works.

This might be useful to someone facing similar issues...

Other solutions are welcome.